# Getting text (read from a file) into a JFrame

Tags: java, text, jframe

very new to writing Java, so am grateful for any help I can get.

I`m trying to create JFrame with text in it read from a separate text file (there are 5 paragraphs, each appearing one after the other). I need help making the text appear on the JFrame (not so worried about the delayed effect for now), as so far, not been successful. Am I far off the mark with the code below? I know this a common problem, but other threads have been dealing with events and other (for me) difficult ideas, and taking what I need from such code is still a challenge for me.

I have read I need a JLabel for the text to go on (although elsewhere I read JPanel?). I believe I also need a method for displaying the text in the StoryFrame class, where I can add the JLabel (and possibly state the nextLine commands so as to help create the delayed effect, instead of putting it into my ShowIntro class - I intend to repeat this process repeatedly). The cmd also made me aware that I have a call to a non-static method from a static place - tried looking in my Java for Dummies text but still can`t figure out how to resolve this. I know this code is insufficient, what am I missing?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class StoryFrame extends JFrame {
        public StoryFrame() {
        setTitle("見張ってしながら...");
        setSize(400,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void displayText() {
        JLabel Text = new JLabel();
        add(Text); // I feel I need to add a lot more here to connect the two classes

        }
}


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class ShowIntro {
 public static void main(String args[]) 
                throws IOException {

    new StoryFrame();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("Intro.txt"));

    while (reader.hasNext()) {
    StoryFrame.displayText();       
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: See [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,java.lang.Object)). Simpler than using a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ShowIntro {
 public static void main(String args[]) 
                throws IOException {

    new StoryFrame();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("Intro.txt"));

    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        StoryFrame.displayText(); // 1 & 2     
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
        }
    }
 }
}
```

When looking at your `ShowIntro` class I notice 2 strange things:

1. You are calling a non-static method (`displayText()`) on a class.
2. You don't pass that what the scanner reads into that method call.

To fix (1) you should pass the instance of the StoryFrame class into a variable, and replace `StoryFrame` with the name of this variable in the marked line.
To fix (2) you should add one parameter to the method `displayText()`, so replace the header of that method in the StoryFrame class with `public void displayText(String text) {` and pass the text read by the scanner when you call the method from the `ShowIntro` class.

Corrected version (untested)

```
class ShowIntro {
 public static void main(String args[]) 
                throws IOException {

    StoryFrame frame = new StoryFrame();                  // Store the StoryFrame in a variable
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("Intro.txt"));

    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        frame.displayText(reader.next());               // pass the text read by the scanner to the displayText() method
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
        }
    }
 }
}
```

And the `displayText()` method from the StoryFrame class:

```
public void displayText(String text) {       // One parameter: a String
    JLabel Text = new JLabel(text);          // Use the String; make it the content of the JLabel
    add(Text);                               // Now add the JLabel to the JFrame.
}
```

Comment: I have words in my frame!! - not all the words, but that`s tomorrow`s challenge ^_^ (I just need to play around with the nextLine function). Thank you for helping clear this up for me, I see where I went wrong now.

Comment: Oh, and one thing yet: the convention is to _not_ start variable names with a capital, only Class names should.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your displayText() is not a static method, therefore you can't call a non-static method from a static one, which is main, without calling it on a object of your class.

You need something like that:

```
StoryFrame sf = new StoryFrame();
sf.displayText();
```

Otherwise if you do this:

```
StoryFrame.displayText();
```

The compiler will expect displayText to be a static method, which it isn't.

Don't try to make displayText() a static method because this will create new problems as you're calling non-static methods from displayText. So just create a StoryFrame object and call displayText() on it.

Also a piece of advice, don't use for dummies books, they're useless.
A great book that I'd recommend for learning Java is something called Big Java. It will teach you lots of stuff.

Also as @schippi mentioned your displayText() methods needs a parameter, which will be the text that you're adding to the JLabel.

Comment: I thought I made that mistake, thanks for clearing that up.

Also, thanks for the recommendation - will check Big Java out. Dummies helped me in the sense that it made java accessible, but you`re right, for hardcore stuff, it`s not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

JPanel is just a container for other components.
a JLabel can contain text.
you want to add text to a JLabel.

you need a JLabel as Objectvariable which you intanciate in the constructor of your frame and add it to the frame

```
private JLabel mylabel;
public StoryFrame() {
    setTitle("見張ってしながら...");
    setSize(400,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mylabel=new JLabel();
    this.add(mylabel);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

now you want the text from the scanner, which is done by

```
reader.next()
```

then you want to change the text of the label.

```
mylabel.setText(text);
```

to append something you can to

```
mylabel.setText(mylabel.getText()+text);
```

i hope you can work out the rest for yourself

tip: your displaytext method needs a parameter